# Is there is any way to call copy constructor from member function in template class?

Tags: c++

I am trying to call copy constructor from class method (I read that it is not possible ) but I have the need to do this, just for learning and understanding.
Here is what I am trying to do-

```
     template<class TYPE>
   class Stack {

    public :

      Stack(){count = 0;}
      Stack(TYPE const &  );                            
      void Push(TYPE  );
      void Show();

    private :
      std::vector<TYPE> Elem_Vec;
      std::size_t count ; 

};
```

Here is my definition

```
 template<class TYPE >
  Stack<TYPE>:: Stack(TYPE const & elem_vec ){
   Elem_Vec.push_back(elem_vec ); ++count; 
}// end

template<class TYPE >
  void Stack<TYPE>::Push(TYPE  elem ){
  *this = elem ;
}// end

  template<class TYPE >
   void Stack<TYPE>:: Show(void ){
   std::cout << "Number of Elemnets in  stack : " << count << std::endl;
  }
```

This is my main

```
int main(void ){
 Stack<int> obj;
 for(int i = 10 ; i < 13 ; ++i )
    obj.Push(i);
    obj.Show();
    return 0;
 }
```

Firstly I was getting the shadow error as I was trying to call the constructor directly from `Push()` and now I am getting the infinite loop. Please help and please do explain. THANKS!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with copy constructors. Your `Push()` should be adding the element to  `Elem_vec`. Additionally, `count` serves no purpose, whatsoever. If you want to get the size of the stack, use `Elem_vec.size();`.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can use `puch_back()` there but I want to call constructor explicitly.Thanks @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Your program executes fine for me, with one issue that `count` is used uninitialized in `Stack<TYPE>::Stack(TYPE const&);`

Comment: It is showing number of element is one. Forget `count`, I tried to use `size()` in `show()` and it is showing 1. Thanks! @aschepler

Comment: Yes, the size of the vector will always be 1, because `*this = elem;` copies a stack constructed with the single element `elem`.

Comment: then how to check how many elements are there in vector or main issue, I have `pop()` which I am calling from `show()` inside `while`, now, the issue is how to stop `while` as I don't know how to get number of elements in vector? @aschepler